# How can I get `\texttt` in `\href` to work with Springer Nature's sn-jnl class?

Tags: xparse, href, springernature

Using version `2019/11/18` of [Springer's `sn-jnl.cls` template](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support) (archived as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/JasonGross/b5985dc7a4fe3c894487a9520adee770)), I get the following:

```
\documentclass{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\githublink}{m m o}{\href{}{\texttt{}}}
\begin{document}
. \githublink{}{}[]
\end{document}
```

```
! Argument of \XKV@d@fine@k@y has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.5 . \githublink{}{}[]
```

What's going on here, and how do I fix this?

**EDIT**

This can be further minimized to

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}%
%%\RequirePackage{hypcap}%
\gdef\breakurldefns{%
%\if@pdflatex\else%
  \RequirePackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}%
  \let\href\burlalt%
  %\fi
}%
\breakurldefns%
%    \bgroup
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
. \href{}{\texttt{}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you do not need xparse with current latex releases, which latex format are you using (current is `LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1`)

Comment: your MWE is missing `\makeatletter` for `\if@pdflatex`

Comment: this is unrelated to newdocumentcommand you can simplify your example to `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
\begin{document}
. \burlalt{}{\texttt{}}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thank you, MWE now fixed

Comment: `\texttt{\burlalt{a}{b}}` works. On the other hand, `\texttt` seems completely redundant.

Comment: the 2nd argument is the URL to link to, did you intend to put the font change in the first argument?

Comment: Ew, really?  Why the heck does sn-jnl swap around the arguments to `\href`?  (Alternatively, why do hyperref and breakurl pick different argument orders for `\href` and `\burlalt`?)

Comment: i just used  `burlalt{aaa}{bbb}`  and it typeset aaa and made a link to bb

Comment: Yes, and if you use `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{hyperref} \begin{document} \href{aaa}{bbb} \end{document}`, it typesets `bbb` (without `texttt`) and makes a link to `aaa`

Comment: assuming that you use pdflatex, you should load the class with the option `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The breakurl package shouldn't be used with pdflatex, but to avoid that it is loaded you must load the class with the option `pdflatex` as the class is a bit dump and doesn't make use of existing methods to detect the output mode automatically.

```
\documentclass[pdflatex]{sn-jnl}
\begin{document}

\href{abc}{\texttt{abc}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
\begin{document}

. \burlalt{aaaa}{bbb}
\end{document}
```

You get

[image]

so the first argument is typeset, you can use font changes there. The second argument is the URL

Comment: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{hyperref} \usepackage{breakurl} \begin{document} \burlalt{\texttt{aaaa}}{bbbb} \end{document}` still fails, but `\texttt{\burlalt{aaaa}{bbbb}}` succeeds.

Comment: but not if you compile with latex, then you get bbb, and in the OP's class breakurl is only used in dvi mode (hoping that \if@pdflatex does what is claim it does).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer eek, I'd delete but it's accepted, Jason if you accepted Ulrike's answer...